# How to control manual double-side printing on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, printing

I have an HP 1022 printer attached to my Mac OS X Lion.

When I try to print a 4-page PDF file from Preview or Adobe Reader, it prints pages 1 and 3 and then all 3 lights on the HP 1022 printer start blinking.

I suspect that perhaps the printer or the system is in some kind of manual double-side printing mode, but I could not find where I can turn it on or off using the Mac OS printing dialogs.

How can one control manual double-side printing on a Mac OS X Lion?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can go to `Print & Scan` in the system preferences and select `Options & Supplies` for your printer. In there, you should see an option for `Duplex Unit` (if your printer supports it). If that is checked, you can use the automatic double-side printing (by checking the `Two-sided` box next to `Copies`). If not, or if that option is unavailable, you can't.

[image]

In case you can't select that option, here's how you can manually print double-sided pages.

#### Manual double-side printing

You can control manual double-side printing (i.e., you physically turn the sheets over) using the `Paper Handling` setting in the print dialog.

If you select `Paper Handling`, you'll find a `Pages to Print` option that lets you print either only the odd pages or only the even pages (default is both). To print double side manually, select `Odd Only` first and when it finishes printing, flip the pages over and select `Even Only`

[image]

Instead of flipping *each page* over to its blank side before printing the even pages, you have a more convenient option of flipping *the entire block of pages*, so that the last sheet is on top (useful when you have a lot of pages to be printed). With this, you can then choose `Reverse` in `Page Order` to print the even numbered pages backwards. (Note: be careful that if you have an odd-number of pages in total, you might have to leave the last one out before printing the even ones.)

[image]

Comment: Now I'm curious what was sensitive enough in your printer's name to need censoring.

Answer (score 1):

In a search, I just found this great tool from HP that facilitates manual duplex printing from OSX with minimal steps. I just tried it with success using my Epson NX-515.

http://whp-hou9.cold.extweb.hp.com/pub/softlib/software12/COL35975/mp-88750-2/HP_Two-sided_Printing.dmg

Answer (score 1):

With my printer I can:

1. Select Paper Handling > Pages to Print > Odd Only and print the pages.
2. Insert the pile of papers on the tray again so that the printed side is facing up and the text is not upside down.
3. Select Paper Handling > Pages to Print > Even Only and print the pages.

With a printer that prints on the other side, follow the steps described by rm -rf:

1. Select Paper Handling > Pages to Print > Odd Only and print the pages.
2. If the total number of pages is odd, remove the last page
3. Flip the pile of papers and insert it on the tray.
4. Select Paper Handling > Pages to Print > Even Only, select Paper Handling > Pages to Print > Reverse, and print the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that for my printer at least (a Brother HL-3070CW), it's easier to:

- print the **even** pages **first**
- flip the pages so the printed side is up and put them back in the tray
- print the **odd** pages

This way you end up with the pages in the correct order when finished and don't have to worry about selecting *reverse*.